# Keep the error bars in foreground in Excel scatter chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

Often in my work I place vertical scatter data inside a graph and overlay a single data point corresponding to the average of that group of data. When I place error bars on that average, the error bars fall to the background and the rest of the data markers obfuscate it.

Is there a way to keep the error bars in the foreground without resorting to changing the markers to be hollow?

Example:
[image: Example of hidden error bars]

(Using Office 2016)

Comment: This might help you: https://superuser.com/a/817989/863212

Comment: @Gangula the answer linked doesn't help the foreground position of the error bars. The bars are still behind everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. Click on the data series that contains the averages (and error bars linked to them), and change the default to "Plot this series" on the "secondary y axis".
Then you just have to ensure that the primary and secondary axes have similar settings to that everything matches!

Comment: I won't be able to use that secondary axis for anything else but that works well enough for my needs. It's ridiculous that we have to go to such lengths...I don't have the rep to up vote you but I am marking your answer correct. Thanks for the help